# ValidationError in mongoose/nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I want to add products to the database (MongoDB) . The program is in loop mode and does not crash, but it shows the error in the console.

> Console content included on the bottom

models/single-product.js

```js
// models/single-product.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const productSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)
```

models/user.js

```js
// models/user.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String ,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String ,
        required: true
    },
    cart: {
        items:[
            {
               productId: {
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: 'Product',
                  required: true
               }, 
               qty:{
                type: Number ,
                required: true
               }
            }
        ]
    }
})
module.exports =mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

controllers/admin.js

```js
// constrollers/admin.js

const Product = require('../models/single-product')

module.exports.addProductsPage = (req,res)=> {
    res.render('admin/add-product',{
        pageTitle: "Add Product-Page"
    })
}

module.exports.sendProducts = (req,res)=>{
    const title = req.body.title
    const description = req.body.description
    const price = req.body.price
    const products = new Product({
        title: title,
        description: description ,
        price: price,
        userId: req.user
    })
    products.save()
    .then(result =>{
        console.log('Product Created!')
        res.redirect('/admin/add-product')
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
    
}
module.exports.getProducts = (req,res)=>{
    Product.find()
        .then(products =>{
            res.render('admin/products',{
                productsArray : products,
                pageTitle : 'Admin Products'
            })
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err)
        })
}
module.exports.deleteProduct = (req,res)=>{
    const pId = req.body.productId
    Product.findByIdAndRemove(pId)
    .then(()=>{
        console.log('Product Deleted!')
        res.redirect('products')
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

```
Error [ValidationError]: Product validation failed: userId: Path `userId` is required.
at ValidationError.inspect (D:\Alireza\web\Test project's\OnlineShop-Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:59:24)
at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:550:31)
at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:221:10)
at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1651:40)
at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:272:10)
at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:282:61)
at D:\Alireza\web\Test project's\OnlineShop-Node.js\controllers\admin.js:25:17
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5) {
```

errors: {
    userId: MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Path `userId` is required.
        at new ValidatorError (D:\Alireza\web\Test project's\OnlineShop-Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:29:11)
        at validate (D:\Alireza\web\Test project's\OnlineShop-Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1034:13)
        at D:\Alireza\web\Test project's\OnlineShop-Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1088:11
        at Array.forEach ()
        at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\Alireza\web\Test project's\OnlineShop-Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1043:14)
        at D:\Alireza\web\Test project's\OnlineShop-Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2134:9
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
      message: 'Path `userId` is required.',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'userId',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'Product validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError'
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPwX5.png)

Answer (score 2):

First check if `req.user` is not null, then save product using

```
const products = new Product({
        title: title,
        description: description ,
        price: price,
        userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user);
    })
```

> you need to make `userId` as `objectID`

Comment: Tnx @Vinil . I edited `userId` to  `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user)` , And the problem was fixed. Thank you so much .

Comment: You are most welcome, please accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Content-Type` property which by default is `text/plain`.
Because of this `text/plain` MongoDB doesn't validate your request.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; // Previous Value
Content-Type: application/json // Changed value
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check This Section of Code in controllers/admin.js.

```
const products = new Product({
        title: title,
        description: description ,
        price: price,
        userId: req.user
    })
```

you are inserting the userId with an undefined or null value. I think req.user is undefined and as you defined **the schema of userId column with required true constraints** in you model:

```
userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
```

Please check this log before inserting the data

```
console.log(req.user);
```